# ALT and SLT synchronous/Asynchronous locally timed in MIPS

Tags: asynchronous, mips

Can anyone please tell me the difference between ALT and SLT?

Another thing: how `SRA` instruction works with `shamt`?

Reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20201111203150/http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

Comment: What do you mean by `ALT`? There's no such instruction on MIPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SRA` is an arithmetic right shift, meaning that it shifts in the original sign bit rather than zeroes.

For example:

```
li $t0,0x80000000
sra $t0,$t0,4
# $t0 now contains 0xF8000000

li $t0,0x40000000
sra $t0,$t0,4
# $t0 now contains 0x04000000
```